# Splitting a string and adding to list using Regex and C#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string where the number of words might vary. Like:

```
string a_string = " one two three four five six seven etc etc etc ";
```

How do I split the string into 5 words each, and each of those are added it to a list, such that it becomes a list of string (with each string containing 5 words). I think list would be better because number of words in string can vary, so list can grow or shrink accordingly.

I tried using Regex to get first 5 words through below line of code:

`Regex.Match(rawMessage, @"(\w+\s+){5}").ToString().Trim();`

but bit unsure on how to proceed further and add to list dynamically and robustly. I guess Regex can further help, or some awesome string/list function? Can you please guide me a bit?

Eventually, I would want list[0] to contain "one two three four five" and list[1] to contain "six seven etc etc etc", and so on.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting for words does not require regex, string provides this capability:

```
var list = str.Split(' ').ToList();
```

`ToList()` is a LINQ extension method for converting `IEnumerable<T>` objects to lists (`Split()` method returns an array of strings).

To group a list by 5 words, use this code snippet:

```
var res = list
    .Select((s, i) => new { Str = s, Index = i })
    .GroupBy(p => p.Index/5)
    .Select(g => string.Join(" ", g.Select(v => v.Str)));
```

Comment: @Tigran The aggregation in the end is a second subquestion, and there is no clarity about how he wants to re-aggregate. It's clear that the OP is stuck at converting results if a split to a list.

Comment: @Tigran For an example of how re-grouping is done without a loop, take a look at my update.

Answer (score 4):

```
var listOfWords = Regex.Matches(a_string, @"(\w+\s+){1,5}")
     .Cast<Match>()
     .Select(i => i.Value.Trim())
     .ToList();
```

Comment: it works fine for the listOfWords[0], but I am not able to access rest of the words via listOfWords[1] and so on.. If the string contained 100 words, I would love to have 20 strings of 5 words each from listOfWords[0] to listOfWords[19]. Also, if there were 97 words even then it would be the same, except that listOfWords[19] gets only 2 words. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: It works fine to get `listOfWords[1]`, I will change the code to cover 97 words.

Comment: for listOfWords[1], I am getting " Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index ". :-/

Comment: Are you using `Regex.Matches`, not `Regex.Matche` ?

Comment: I am using it as it is, i.e. Regex.Matches.

Comment: There must be something wrong in your code, it works fine on my PC and [here](http://ideone.com/dNbKf)

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple

```
a_string.Split(' ');
```

And then loop throught resulting array and fill your list as you want, for example

```
int numOfWords = 0;
int currentPosition = 0;
foreach (var str in a_string.Split(' '))
{
   if (numOfWords == 5)
   {
     numOfWords = 0;
     currentPosition++;
   }
   list[currentPosition] += str;
   numOfWords++;
}
```